# Using Protobuf installed at a custom location in Linux with CMake?

Tags: linux, cmake, protocol-buffers

I am packaging all my dependencies with Conan IO for a C++ project using CMake. I downloaded the sources of Protobuf and built them. I then added them on Conan.

On a build server, I am trying to build my CMake project, but it cannot seem to find my Protobuf library properly. Here's the log I am getting:

```
/home/user/Documents/project/test/build/venv/.conan/data/Protobuf/3.6.1/org/dev/package/80043e232e8ab07f4b25e67652a9490d9ad33d91/bin/protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake Warning at /home/username/Documents/project/test/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version doesn't match library version 3.6.1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/username/Documents/project/test/script/cmake/Env.cmake:139 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)


-- Found Protobuf: /home/username/Documents/project/test/build/venv/.conan/data/Protobuf/3.6.1/org/dev/package/80043e232e8ab07f4b25e67652a9490d9ad33d91/lib/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread (found version "3.6.1") 
/home/username/Documents/project/test/build/venv/.conan/data/Protobuf/3.6.1/org/dev/package/80043e232e8ab07f4b25e67652a9490d9ad33d91/bin/protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.17: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake Warning at /home/username/Documents/project/test/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version doesn't match library version 3.6.1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/username/Documents/project/test/src/shared/bysp/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Found Protobuf: /home/username/Documents/project/test/build/venv/.conan/data/Protobuf/3.6.1/org/dev/package/80043e232e8ab07f4b25e67652a9490d9ad33d91/lib/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread;-lpthread (found version "3.6.1")
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. It says it cannot find `libprotoc.so.17`, but that file exists under `/lib` in my conan package. It then says that it did find my library. I don't understand why it's giving me a warning and then says that it found the library. Also, protobuf is not installed on the build server. All dependencies are pre-built binaries downloaded via Conan. I am using `FindProtobuf` to find `protobuf`. Should I use something else?